# update database after sending sms

Tags: android, smsmanager

In my project I used `SmsManager` to send message to my client. If the sms is sent successfully I want to change client status in client table. This class named PassengerInformation.java is an `activity` used to send sms and change status of client in db. There is a problem I found that is PassengerInformation activity run code of updating status of client without knowing sms is sent successfully, it have to wait running code of updating until sms is successfully sent by `SmsManager`.

**PassengerInformation.java**

```
public class PassengerInformation extends BaseFragment{
public static Boolean messageSending= false;
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    SendSMS sms=new SendSMS(v.getContext());
    sms.sendSMS("83939420",builder.toString());
    if(messageSending){
       //update database
   }
}
```

**SendSMS.java**

```
public class SendSMS {
  Context mContext;
  String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
  String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

  ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents;
  ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents;

public SendSMS(Context c){
    mContext=c;
}
 public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {               

        SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> parts =sm.divideMessage(message);
        int numParts = parts.size();

        sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++) {
            sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0));
            deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0));
            }
        //---when the SMS has been sent---
        mContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        PassengerInformation.messageSending=true;
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        PassengerInformation.messageSending=false;
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        PassengerInformation.messageSending=false;
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Null PDU",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        PassengerInformation.messageSending=false;
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Radio off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        PassengerInformation.messageSending=false;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        //---when the SMS has been delivered---
        mContext.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        PassengerInformation.messageSending=true;
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        PassengerInformation.messageSending=false;
                        break;                        
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents); 
    }   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem I found that is PassengerInformation activity run code of updating status of client without knowing sms is sent successfully, it have to wait running code of updating until sms is successfully sent by SmsManager.--> for that you have to keep your update db code  in switch/case of SendSMS class.

```
 case Activity.RESULT_OK:
     Toast.makeText(mContext, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     PassengerInformation.messageSending=true;

     if(messageSending){
       //update database
      }
 break;
```

Comment: it would be better if you move the code for updating table on case Activity.RESULT_OK:
or use if else cases and return boolean at the end of sms sending code if the boolean returns true then update the table, hope this will be helpful